# Database Abstraction to Fetch published content of specific content type throwing error

Tags: database

I'm attempting to grab all published content of type 'homepage_slide', as currently my slider loads all content unpublished or otherwise.

Here is my current Abstraction query.

```
  if ($variables['is_front']) {

    // Create data for slider
    // Get from DB nids of content type homepage_slide
    $query = \Drupal::database()->select('node', 'n');
      $query->fields('n', ['nid']);
      $query->condition('n.type', 'homepage_slide');
      $query->condition('n.status', 1);
      $nids = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

    $variables['home_page']['slides'] = array();

    // get and set values from content type to variable
    foreach ($nids as $val) {
      $node = Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($val->nid);

      $text = $node->get('body')->getValue();
      $img = $node->get('field_image')->getValue();
      $link_url = $node->get('field_button_link')->first()->getUrl();
      $link_title = $node->get('field_button_link')->first()->title;

      $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($img[0]['target_id']);
      $img_src = $file->url();

      $variables['home_page']['slides'][] = array(
        'text' => ['#markup' => $text[0]['value']],
        'img_src' => $file->url(),
        'link_url' => $link_url,
        'link_title' => $link_title
      );
    }

  }
```

When I remove the line `$query->condition('n.status', 1);` it works. However throws the below error when I leave it in.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper</em>: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;status&#039; in &#039;where clause&#039;: SELECT n.nid AS nid
FROM
{node} n
WHERE (n.type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (status = :db_condition_placeholder_1); Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; homepage_slide
    [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =&gt; 1
)
 in <em class="placeholder">themename_preprocess_page()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">126</em> of <em class="placeholder">themes/themename/themename.theme</em>). <pre class="backtrace">Drupal\Core\Database\Statement-&gt;execute(Array, Array) (Line: 631)
Drupal\Core\Database\Connection-&gt;query(&#039;SELECT n.nid AS nid
FROM
{node} n
WHERE (n.type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (status = :db_condition_placeholder_1)&#039;, Array, Array) (Line: 358)
Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection-&gt;query(&#039;SELECT n.nid AS nid
FROM
{node} n
WHERE (n.type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (status = :db_condition_placeholder_1)&#039;, Array, Array) (Line: 510)
Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Select-&gt;execute() (Line: 126)
themename_preprocess_page(Array, &#039;page&#039;, Array) (Line: 287)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager-&gt;render(&#039;page&#039;, Array) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;render(Array) (Line: 501)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension-&gt;escapeFilter(Object, Array, &#039;html&#039;, NULL, 1) (Line: 176)
__TwigTemplate_e559a627712398e644a3084e1d00b70842705a0f1b596808c95e6be526e73217-&gt;doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 455)
Twig\Template-&gt;displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 422)
Twig\Template-&gt;display(Array) (Line: 434)
Twig\Template-&gt;render(Array) (Line: 64)
twig_render_template(&#039;themes/themename/templates/html.html.twig&#039;, Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager-&gt;render(&#039;html&#039;, Array) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;render(Array) (Line: 147)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer-&gt;Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 148)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer-&gt;renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber-&gt;onViewRenderArray(Object, &#039;kernel.view&#039;, Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, &#039;kernel.view&#039;, Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher-&gt;dispatch(&#039;kernel.view&#039;, Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 693)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel-&gt;handle(Object) (Line: 19)
</pre>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The node table doesn't have a status column in Drupal 8. Use node_field_data or preferably use EntityQuery to build your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`Drupal::entityQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x). The node table doesn't contain the status.

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type','homepage_slide')
  ->condition('status', 1);
  ->execute();

$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);

// Loop through all nodes.
foreach ($nodes as $node) {

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! To confirm, I straight replace the 5 lines above with the 4 you posted here?

Comment: @RobHern – Yepp, exactly. Then debug what's inside `$nids`, for example with Devel's submodule Kint you could do `ksm($nids);`. And then continue whatever you wanted to do with these node IDs.

Comment: Thanks! I have this already in my function, previously working as intended - I've updated the original question with that code now also - but it's throwing an error of `AssertionError: Cannot load a NULL ID. in assert() (line 249 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).`. Is this due to how I've grabbed the node content?

Comment: @RobHern – Updated answer. As I said, you can debug what's inside the variables with Kint's `ksm($val)` etc.

Comment: @RobHern – **The worst thing about this is that you seem to be doing this from within a preprocess function. Where it actually should be a Views block. And then you don't need this code at all.**

Comment: I inherited this code from a previous colleague, so I'm not averse to learning a better or easier version to achieve this. I'll look into views blocks. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @RobHern – The Views block will take care of the caching for example. As soon as an editor adds or changes a slide Views will recognize it and display the updated slides. With the current approach you have to rebuild the caches manually to get the changes to be displayed.